# Makefile to run a Maven command, but commands has ":" character

Tags: maven, makefile

Small question regarding a Makefile please. We are currently using a Makefile in order to run commands. (Many many of them). One particular command, which is a java Maven build, is failing.

Here is the snippet of the Makefile:

```
.PHONY: help
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

help: ## This help.
    @awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "} /^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## / {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

build:
    mvn clean install -U -Pintegration -Dspringdoc.writer-with-default-pretty-printer=true javadoc:javadoc checkstyle:checkstyle spotbugs:spotbugs pmd:pmd pmd:cpd org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage jacoco:prepare-agent jacoco:report dependency:tree sonar:sonar
```

To emphasise, `make build` here is not doing anything:

```
make build
make: Nothing to be done for `build'.
```

On an IDE, I can see the error:

```
$, <conditional>, <directive>, EOL, '\t' or macro expected, got ':'
```

To also add information, this works:

```
.PHONY: help
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

help: ## This help.
    @awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "} /^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## / {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

clean: ## mvn clean
    mvn clean;
```

Invoking `make clean` will actually clean. make help is also working.

But not working for this rule:

```
build:
    mvn clean install -U -Pintegration -Dspringdoc.writer-with-default-pretty-printer=true javadoc:javadoc checkstyle:checkstyle spotbugs:spotbugs pmd:pmd pmd:cpd org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage jacoco:prepare-agent jacoco:report dependency:tree sonar:sonar
```

I do not understand what does it means.
May I ask how to fix this please?

To confirm, the exact same maven command run from a terminal works perfectly fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remove the `@` from the command and see what `make` really passes as a command line to `awk`.

Comment: Which command is failing? make help? make build?

Comment: The makefile is OK. Your "IDE" is getting confused.

Comment: the rule that is not being triggered is make build. I updated the question to prove details

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  First you seem to be saying that the commands work fine but your IDE complains.  That's an issue with your IDE, which you don't name here, so you should check your IDE's help / support system and/or ask here with information about which IDE you're using and add appropriate tags; this doesn't seem to be a make or makefile question.  Next you suggest that `make build` is "not working" but you don't provide any error messages, output, etc. so there's no way we can help you solve this problem.

Comment: make build
make: Nothing to be done for `build'.

Comment: I can remove the IDE part if needed. It is not the question. The question is, when I run "make build", I am expecting the actual mvn command to run, and NOT "make: Nothing to be done for `build'."

Comment: You are abusing make as shell scripts, use shell scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Make "call" function.

```
define buildfn
    mvn clean install -U -Pintegration -Dspringdoc.writer-with-default-pretty-printer=true javadoc:javadoc checkstyle:checkstyle spotbugs:spotbugs pmd:pmd pmd:cpd org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage jacoco:prepare-agent jacoco:report dependency:tree sonar:sonar
endef
```

Then run it like this:

```
build:
    $(call buildfn)
```

Here is reference documentation: [The call function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html)

Comment: This is indeed correct, thank you @luqo33, learned something new with makefile